# Windows server 2003 randomly stop responding

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2003, active-directory

We have a Windows2003 server machine that runs AD and is the only domain controller. In the last few days it started to act strangely. It can be accessed from outside via RDP, but it's mostly unaccessible from the LAN. AD users are able to login, but the server doesn't reply to ping and shared folders don't work.

The strange thing is that while most of the computers on the LAN can't access the server, some still can. There's also a DNS problem so Internet access randomly stalls.

I din't find any malware or hardware issue on the server, I can't see anything strange in the event log and we don't have any network issues (other computers can communicate with each other and the controller is readily accessible from outside)

I'm considering a complete reinstall of the controller, but if there's an easier solution, I'd gladly try that.

Answer (score 0):

With buggy DNS, Active Directory is going to respond sporadically.  I am guessing here,  but if your internet goes offline when your DNS server stops responding, that is probably just a symptom of the DNS service having issues.  Odds are (again, I am guessing) that your Windows 2003 server is handling DNS requests for your clients and has forwarders setup to resolve names outside your domain.

Next time it "stalls"  do nslookup from a stuck workstation and see if you are able to resolve out local and remote domain names. Also, check to see if you can ping the IP of the server. Also check to see if simply restarting your DNS server service gets it working.  If so, then dig into the event logs and isolate the DNS server issues.

Comment: There are a few workstations that are on the same LAN but outside of the domain. They have a steady internet connection. Internet connection only goes down on domain members, and if I specify the router as secondary DNS, they can access the internet, but not the AD controller. Coud it be the problem that we have a simple router acting as DHCP server and the AD controller is just running DNS server, but not DHCP?

Comment: That sounds like a DNS issue with the DC.  DHCP should be fine so long as it is passing out DNS pointing to one of the Active Directory Domain Controllers..  If the AD DNS fails and it begins to use the ISPs DNS, your AD setup will fail as Windows relies on DNS for basically everything (that's a gross exageration, but in this case it is relevant.)

Answer (score 0):

We had a file server do this when we did a P2V virtualization on it.  It would do everything except ping or access file shares.  We could reboot it and it would work.  We wound up building a server 2008 machine and migrating over to it.

It was only one server that ever did it and other file servers still functioned.